# Template error no rspec-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Estou usando o **rspec-rails** para testar minha aplicação, entretanto ao testar uma view que usa o **Ransak** para filtros tenho o seguinte erro de retorno:

```
1) admin/cities/index renders a list of admin_cities
   Failure/Error: render
   ActionView::Template::Error:
   No Ransack::Search object was provided to search_form_for!
```

#### Meu controller

```
def index
  @q = City.search(params[:q])
  @cities = @q.result(distinct: true).page params[:page]
end
```

#### Minha view

```
= search_form_for [:admin, @q] do |f|
  = f.text_field :nome_cont
  table
    tr
      th Nome
    - @cities.each do |city|
      tr
        td = city.nome
```

#### Meu teste

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "admin/cities/index", type: :view do
  city_params1 = {codigo_municipio: 1, nome: 'Maringá', uf: 'PR', municipio: 1}
  city_params2 = {codigo_municipio: 2, nome: 'Maringá2', uf: 'PR', municipio: 1}
  before(:each) do
    assign(:admin_cities, [
      City.create!(city_params1),
      City.create!(city_params2)
    ])
  end
  it "renders a list of admin_cities" do
    render
  end
end
```

O que poderia resolver isto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicionar o código seguinte no começo do teste:

```
before(:each) do
  assign :q, City.ransack
end
```